# Android : How to get the top-level parent layout of an activity

Tags: android, android-layout

I would like to get the top-level layout of this sample android xml layout. The top-level I'm referring to is the ViewGroup that is holding the whole activity together.

I am aware of

```
getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);
```

But I don't need the DecorView.

Please refer to the xml below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout">
        <WebView
        android:id="@+id/my_webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

I need to get the RelativeLayout (which is the top-level layout I'm referring to, please correct me if I'm wrong with my terms). I can get it by using the code below.

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.my_webview);
webview.getParent().getParent()
```

However, what if the Layout is nested deeper like

```
<Layout>
    <Layout>
       <Layout>
          <Webview/>
       <Layout>
    <Layout>
<Layout>
```

How will be able to get the top-level Layout without using getParent(). Thanks!

Comment: give the id to your parent_layout in your .XML and define / cast  this id in your MainActivity and use this id as you want.

Comment: I'm calling this in a library that I did that can be used by different apps. Now, the id thing is not applicable in this one. 
p.s : the id can be different in every app that uses the library. so the only reference that I can have is the webview object.

Comment: I created this code but haven't tested https://hastebin.com/ijiyusicul.cs.

Comment: Checked your code, it won't work because the the top-level layout also has its own parent.

Answer (score 5):

In xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:id="@+id/parentLayout">

    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout">
        <WebView
        android:id="@+id/my_webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

In your activity

```
 RelativeLayout parentLayout=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.parentLayout);
```

or

```
getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
```

or

```
getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);
```

or

```
ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) ((ViewGroup) this
            .findViewById(android.R.id.content)).getChildAt(0);
```

Comment: I'm calling this in a library that I did that can be used by different apps. Now, the id thing is not applicable in this one. p.s : the id can be different in every app that uses the library. so the only reference that I can have is the webview object.

Comment: you can try view group if you do not need getDecorView()